# How to sort a hash map using key descending order

Tags: java

How to sort a hash map using key descending order. please explain with example.
And how many way to sort a hash map.
please explain in details

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`HashMap`s don't support sorting. They store entries in buckets, how they see it fit, just based on the `hashCode` value of the keys. They are fine for storing things and looking them up afterwards, but unsuitable for iterating over their contents (which is what you apparently want to do) because you cannot rely on their order and iterating over it is usually expensive.

Try a `TreeMap` instead. You can specify a custom comparator that does just the reverse of the default comparator. In that case your entries will be ordered in *descending* order. [`Collections.reverseOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder-java.util.Comparator-) will create such a comparator for you, you can use it like this:

```
new TreeMap<Integer, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using this method as included in Java 8.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sorted_map =
                map_1.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here 'map_1' is the map you want to sort.

Now you can use the sorted_map variable to iterate and use for your purpose.

Make sure to :

```
import static java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;
```

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to accomplish this:

1. Using **HashMap**

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
       map.put("A", 34);
       map.put("B", 25);
       map.put("C", 50);
       map.put("D", 50); // "duplicate" value

       System.out.println(entriesSortedByValues(map));
   }

   static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> List<Entry<String, Integer>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<String, Integer> map) {

       List<Entry<String, Integer>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());

       Collections.sort(sortedEntries, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> e1, Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
               return e2.getKey().compareTo(e1.getKey());
           }
       });

       return sortedEntries;
   }
   ```
2. Using **Tree Map**, writing own `Comparator`

   ```
   public class Test2 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
           map.put("A", 34);
           map.put("B", 25);
           map.put("C", 50);
           map.put("D", 50);

           MyComparator comp = new MyComparator(map);

           Map<String, Integer> newMap = new TreeMap(comp);
           newMap.putAll(map);
           System.out.println(newMap);
       }
   }

   class MyComparator implements Comparator {
       Map map;

           public MyComparator(Map map) {
           this.map = map;
       }

       @Override
       public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
           return (o2.toString()).compareTo(o1.toString());
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code

```
public class MapUsingSort {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Map<Integer, String> abc = new HashMap<>();
abc.put(3, "a");
abc.put(6, "b"); 
abc.put(1, "c");
abc.put(4, "h");
abc.put(10, "k");
abc.put(9, "x");

 // Map is stored in ArrayList
List<Entry<Integer,String>> sortedEntries = new 
ArrayList<Entry<Integer,String>>(abc.entrySet());


Collections.sort(sortedEntries, new Comparator<Entry<Integer,String>>() {
 @Override
 public int compare(Entry<Integer, String> a, Entry<Integer, String> b) 
 {
    //Sorting is done here make changes as per your need 
    // swap a and b for descending order in return statement 

    return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());   
 }
});

 for (Object object : sortedEntries) {

  //print your data in your own way
  System.out.println((Map.Entry)object);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
         hmap.put(5, "A");
         hmap.put(11, "C");
         hmap.put(4, "Z");
         hmap.put(77, "Y");
         hmap.put(9, "P");
         hmap.put(66, "Q");
         hmap.put(0, "R");

         System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
         Set set = hmap.entrySet();
         Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
         while(iterator.hasNext()) {
               Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
               System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
               System.out.println(me.getValue());
         }
         Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(hmap); 
         System.out.println("After Sorting:");
         Set set2 = map.entrySet();
         Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
         while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
              Map.Entry me2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
              System.out.print(me2.getKey() + ": ");
              System.out.println(me2.getValue());
         }
    }
```

Comment: No need to iterate over the map to print its content, its `toString` is overloaded to do the same, so `System.out.println(hmap);` is enough. Also, please don't use raw types (like `Set`). And no need to use iterators in this case, a for-each loop will do (`for (Map.Entry me2 : set2)`).

Comment: Besides, the OP asked for *descending* order.

Comment: Also, a little explanation is much better than just a full page of uncommented code.